# using one one event for multiple purpose

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have buttons like this :

```
 <input class="btnRating"  type="button" value="Project Rate" />

 <input class="btnRating"  type="button" value=" Education Rate" />

 <input class="btnRating"  type="button" value="Achievement Rate" />
```

i want to use 3 buttons as per different click ,different purpose

and in one event i want to write like this :

```
// Event For Open Modal Pop for rating
$('.btnRating').on("click", function (ele) {

if(thisbutton ==Project )
{
// do something for project related
}

if(thisbutton ==Education)
{
// do something for Education related
}

if(thisbutton ==Achievement)
{
// do something for project related
}
```

});

how do i write event like this?

Comment: Why not just give them different ids and attach the handler separately? Or just check against `this.value`?

Comment: `if($(this).val() == "....."){.. do this..}`

Comment: i don't want to create 3 events , it is just my curiously, why don't i write like this?

Comment: `if(~this.value.indexOf('Project')){...}else if(){}`

Comment: Pleeeaaase don't do this. Those chains of `if`-statements _never_ lead to clear maintainable code. Instead, follow Manishearth's advise and give them different `id`s with different handlers; or describe your _actual_ problem and we can suggest a more fitting solution,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If clicking each button has completely different consequences**

It's more logical if they are handled by different events. Different meaning they don't share most of their code. Even if you don't want to write three events (why? it's the same amount of lines of codes), it fits better the use case.

**If clicking each button has similar consequences**

This seems to be your case, since all buttons have "Rate" in their name. If so, you are right that you should only have one event, since most of the code will be the same. However, instead of using different code paths (if/else or switches), it's better if you add a `data-` attribute to your buttons to so that, by using the value in those attributes, the same code can behave in different ways. Let's say the only difference between them is a "Rate Multiplier". You could do this:

```
<input type="text" id="costToMultiplyByRate" />
<input class="btnRating"  type="button" value="Project Rate" data-rate="5" />
<input class="btnRating"  type="button" value=" Education Rate" data-rate="4" />
<input class="btnRating"  type="button" value="Achievement Rate" data-rate="10" />

$('.btnRating').on("click", function (ele) {
    var rate = ele.getAttribute("data-rate");
    var cost = document.getElementById("costToMultiplyByRate");
    alert(rate * cost);
}
```

However, if by adding only one or two data attributes you can't make the three buttons use exactly the same code, I suggest you use multiple events.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.btnRating').on("click", function (ele) {
    if (this.value.indexOf('Project') > -1) {
        // do something for project related
    } else if (this.value.indexOf('Education') > -1) {
        // do something for Education related
    } else if (this.value.indexOf('Achievement') > -1) {
        // do something for project related
    }
});
```

Comment: well, firstofall,  i am not the downvoter here... but don't you think instead of getting `indexOf` , comparing the values is far **better and readable** ...anyways you have to write `the corrrespoding value in both cases`. `this.value.indexOf('Project') > -1` || `this.value=='Project'`

Comment: I did downvote.. explanation give by @bipen is more than enough.. what happens if you want to change your values, then you need to change your JS code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the value of the cbutton

```
$('.btnRating').on("click", function (ele) {
    if (this.value == 'Project Rate') {
        // do something for project related
    } else if (this.value == ' Education Rate') {
        // do something for Education related
    } else if (this.value == 'Achievement Rate') {
        // do something for project related
    }
});
```

Better solution is to have a unique selector for the buttons and write separate handlers for each one

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.btnRating').on("click", function (ele) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val == "Project Rate"){
    }
    else if(val == " Education Rate"){
    }
    else if(val == "Achievement Rate"){
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend add classes to buttons

```
<input class="btnRating project"  type="button" value="Project Rate" />

<input class="btnRating education"  type="button" value=" Education Rate" />

<input class="btnRating Achievement"  type="button" value="Achievement Rate" />
```

And then use separated events

```
$('.btnRating.project').on("click", function (ele) {
 // do something for project related
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add attribute : `data-event`

```
<input class="btnRating"  type="button" value="Project Rate" data-event="project" />
```

then u can use a switch

```
$('.btnRating').on("click", function (ele) {
    switch($(this).data("event")) {
        case "project" : 
            //fire your function
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this,

In HTML section:

```
    <input class="btnRating" id="ProjectRate"  type="button" value="Project Rate" />

     <input class="btnRating"  id="EducationRate" type="button" value=" Education Rate" />

     <input class="btnRating" id="AchievementRate"  type="button" value="Achievement Rate" />
```

In Script:

```
 <script>
    $(function(){       
        // Event For Open Modal Pop for rating
        $('.btnRating').click(function (ele) {

            var thisbutton = $(this).attr('id');

            if(thisbutton =="ProjectRate")
            {
            // do something for project related
            }else if(thisbutton =="EducationRate")
            {
            // do something for Education related
            }else if(thisbutton =="AchievementRate")
            {
            // do something for project related
            }else{
            // do your default
              }         
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="btnRating"  type="button" data-action="project" value="Project Rate" />
<input class="btnRating"  type="button" data-action="education" value=" Education Rate" />
<input class="btnRating"  type="button" data-action="achievement" value="Achievement Rate" />

$(".btnRating").click(function () {
    var action = $(this).attr("data-action");
    if (action === "project") {
        // do project

    } else if (action === "education") {
        // do education
    }
});
```

This way you can have any value (text) on the button, which is good if you want to globalize your website in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btnRating').click(function (ele) {

if($(this).val()=="Project Rate" )
{
// do something for project related

}

else if($(this).val() =="Education Rate")
{
// do something for Education related

}

else if($(this).val() =="Achievement Rate")
{
// do something for project related

}

});
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/3Mf3j/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.btnRating').on("click", function (ele) {
    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value.indexOf("Project Rate") != -1)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else if(value.indexOf("Education Rate") != -1)
    {
       // do something
    }
    else if(value.indexOf("Achievement Rate") != -1)
    {
       // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event.delegate http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ - something like http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/zw27q/2/

I will recommend that use unique css classes for each buttons as if you change the Value of each input than you have to change your JS as well. So instead of checking for `val=='Project Rate` you should check for `$this.hasClass('rateProj')`

```
$(".btns").delegate("input", "click", function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val();

    if (val =='Project Rate') {
        //code
    }
    //more if statements
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use data-attribute to achieve this. as comparing string can cause more time for checking...

I have created jsfiddle for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/x4yyp/2/

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnRating", function () {
    var optionValue = $(this).data("optionvalue");
    if(optionValue == 1)
    {
        alert("hello");
    }
    else if(optionValue == 2)
    {
        alert("your name");
    }
    else if(optionValue == 3)
    {
        alert("your email");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help you

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.btnRating').on("click", function (ele) {
        var btnType = $(this).val();
        switch(btnType) {
            case 'Project Rate':
                    // your action;
                break;
            case ' Education Rate':
                // your action;
                break;
            case 'Achievement Rate':
                // your action;
                break;
        }
    });
});
```